# What data structure should I be using to get rid of [ ]?

Tags: java

I have a program that uses a TreeMap to store an index.

```
TreeMap<String,Set<Integer>> map = new TreeMap<String,Set<Integer>>();
```

I then use PrintWriter to save the map to a txt file.

```
PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(outputFile);

for(Map.Entry<String,Set<Integer>> entry : map.entrySet()){
    printWriter.println(entry.getKey()+" "+entry.getValue());
}

printWriter.flush();
printWriter.close();
```

I am trying to make the output outputFile look like this:

```
    ! 5
    "$200 218
    "'deed 115
    "'deed, 304
    "a 5,6,22,28,148,176,302,347,387,401,410,442
```

Instead I am getting this:

```
    ! [5]
    "$200 [218]
    "'deed [115]
    "'deed, [304]
    "a [5,6,22,28,148,176,302,347,387,401,410,442]
```

I suspect that the brackets are because I am using a Set, but I don't know what I should use to not get brackets.

Comment: You could write a class that wraps the `Set` and override that class's `toString()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getValue()` for you returns a `Set` and that's why you get those brackets.

You can iterate through the elements of the set and print them -

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Set<Integer>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
  printWriter.print(entry.getKey()+ " ");
  for( Integer setElement : entry.getValue()) {
     printWriter.print(setElement + " ");
  }
  printWriter.println();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Remember that `Set` is a sort of collection, thus when you want to print their values on a file, *they are rounded by brackets*. If you want to delete this brackets, test the code below:

```
PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(outputFile);

for(Map.Entry<String,Set<Integer>> entry : map.entrySet()){
    printWriter.print(entry.getKey()+" ");
    for(Integer value : entry.getValue()) {
        printWriter.print(value + " ");
    }
    printWriter.print("\n");
}
```

So you don't see this brackets more.

Regards!